# How do I use THEME HOLO and continue with the APP works?

Tags: android

![enter image description here][1]I have a problem with my app. I need to change my **AppTheme**, I utilize **name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light",** but when I change to **android:Theme.Holo**, my app doesn't work.

There are errors when I click in Add Location or a item in my adapter-locations.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.example.pedropaulo.tp2.EditLocationActivity.onCreate(EditLocationActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

My principal activity is:

```
public class SortedLocationsListActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    LocationAdapter adapter;
    InputStream inputStream;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        adapter = new LocationAdapter(this,R.layout.row_location);


        try
        {

            inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.locations);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String recebe_string;

            while ( (recebe_string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
            {

                String[] a= recebe_string.split(";");
                adapter.addLocation(a[0],a[1],a[2]);

            }

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

            inputStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sorted_locations_list, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_settings:

                Intent loc = new Intent(this,EditLocationActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(loc, 1);
                // Lancez votre EditLocationActivity

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                String Adres = data.getStringExtra("Address");
                String Nom = data.getStringExtra("Name");

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                long la = c.getTimeInMillis();
                String Dat = Long.toString(la);

                adapter.addLocation(Nom, Adres, Dat);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        LocationAdapter.Location loca = (LocationAdapter.Location) adapter.getItem(position);

        Intent intent1;
        intent1 = new Intent(SortedLocationsListActivity.this, MapActivity.class);

        intent1.putExtra("nome",loca.name);
        intent1.putExtra("endereco",loca.address);
        intent1.putExtra("datis",loca.date);


       Log.d("teste ", loca.name);


        startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appcompat-v7` activities, including `ActionBarActivity`, only support the `AppCompat` themes. If you don't want to use the `AppCompat` themes, you will need to extend some other class such as `Activity`.

Comment: Do I need only change the extend?

Comment: Given the code you posted, it looks like you'll be fine extending from Activity. Keep in mind, though, that if you're not using the appcompat activities or themes, you won't get most of the benefits of appcompat like action bars on pre-Honeycomb devices or Material styling.